# How to make Java GUI settext recognize new lines for a 2 dimensional array input

Tags: java, string, swing, jlabel, settext

I have a char[xSize][ySize] being sent to my GUI. The GUI prints the long string as one long line without recognizing the new lines in it. What method or code could I use?
The code I currently use is:

```
            JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Start Screen");
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            frame1.setSize(500, 500);
            frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame1.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            //Code to recieve from other program:

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            String Sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());  

            //Print received text to GUI:
            label.setText(Sentence);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something `JLabel`, you would need to first replace the new lines (`\n`) with `<br>` and wrap the text in `<html>...</html>`

```
String Sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());  

//Print received text to GUI:
label.setText("<html>" + Sentence.replaceAll("\n", "<br>") + "</html>");
```

Or you might be able to use a non-editable `JTextArea` instead...

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, now I have the problem of the allignment though. Could you please tell me how to fix it? For example: for the following output: "+ + +<br>+B+ +", the + signs in the lower line arent exactly under the + sign in upper line. There is a shift because of the b. How can I get rid of that? Thank you

Comment: Use a fixed width font

Comment: label.setText(...) into invokeLater